# How can I hunt express.js memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks, profiling

I'm using Express.js version 4.12.2 which runs in cluster mode managed by forever process monitor on a Linux machine.

Yesterday the free memory of the machine was around 50% which suddenly rose to 98%.

There was some traffic on the application. But memory was not GCed.

I took heap-dumps of the application but could not find any footprints or leftovers.

What may be other memory hogs/memory leaks that may be there.

Next step I took was to see if are closing DB connections properly and found that we are not closing them.
- I asked it in a separate question- [Using Q.deferred and mysql connection closing in express,js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600055/using-q-deffered-and-mysql-connection-closing-in-express-js)

ps - I will keep this questions updated what I'm upto.

Comment: You should consider doing dtrace with a flamegraph visualizer as well since you're on Linux. It can show you wonders.